# What is the difference between "undefined" and undefined?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying this quiz in the Chrome console: [Quiz](http://perfectionkills.com/javascript-quiz/)

I can explain most of them somewhat after trying them out. But one thing confuses me:

```
var x = [typeof x, typeof y][1];
    typeof typeof x;
```

.... returns "string", which doesn't make any sense to me.

```
var x = [typeof x, typeof y][1];
```

returns "undefined"

`typeof "undefined"`

returns "string", which makes some sense because undefined was in quotes. But overall, I don't see the purpose of "undefined" in coexistance with undefined. Also, what kind of array syntax is that? "Javascript The Good Parts" says that there are no multidimensional arrays.

Comment: check this out to know how undefined is related to scope 
https://codepen.io/grumpy/post/undefined-scope-in-javascript

Answer (score 39, accepted):

1. `undefined` is actually `window.undefined` in most situations. **It's just a variable**.
2. `window.undefined` happens *to not be defined*, unless someone defines it (try `undefined = 1` and `typeof undefined` will be `"number"`).
3. `typeof` is **an operator** that **always returns a string**, describing the type of a value.
4. `typeof window.undefined` gives you `"undefined"` - again, just a string.
5. `typeof "undefined"` gives `"string"`, just like `typeof "foo"` would.
6. Therefore, `typeof typeof undefined` gives `"string"`.

---

In relation to this syntax:

```
[1, 2][1];
```

That's not a multi-dimensional array - it is merely creating an array first `arr = [1, 2]`, and then selecting element 1 from it: `arr[1]`.

Answer (score 4):

`undefined` is a global that is undefined by default.

`typeof` returns a string which describes the type of the object.

So:

```
 [typeof x, typeof y][1];
 [typeof undefined, typeof undefined][1];
 ["undefined", "undefined"][1];
 "undefined"

 typeof "undefined" == "string"
 typeof undefined == "undefined"
 typeof 1 == "number"
 typeof {} == "object"
```

> Also, what kind of array syntax is that?

It is an array literal with `[1]` on the end so it returns the object at index 1.

> "Javascript The Good Parts" says that there are no multidimensional arrays.

There aren't, but an array can contain other arrays. This one doesn't though.

Answer (score 1):

`"undefined"` is a string (literal), undefined is ehr ... `undefined`

`var x = [typeof x, typeof y][1]` supposedly returns the string `"undefined"` (from `typeof y`). Now if you ask for `typeof "undefined"`, it returns the string `"string"`. And if you ask for the `typeof "string"` It (again) returns `"string"` ofcourse.

It's safe to say that `typeof [anything]`  always returns a string (literal), so `typeof typeof something` would always be "string".

Comment: I think it's useful to say that "undefined" is a string LITERAL as it's in quotes

Answer (score 1):

Whoa, this is a tough one to explain. The "typeof" operator returns a string, describing the type of its operand. So:

```
typeof undefined
```

returns the string "undefined", and

```
typeof typeof undefined
```

returns the string "string", which is the type of the string "undefined". I think it's confusing because undefined is both a type and a value.

Second part: there are indeed no multidimensional arrays (as such) in JavaScript. In this expression:

```
var x = [typeof x, typeof y][1];
```

The first set of square brackets is an array literal consisting of 2 elements. The second set of square brackets references element 1 of that array (typeof y). So that expression is effectively equivalent to this:

```
var x = typeof y;
```

Answer (score 1):

1. `[typeof x, typeof y]` is a normal array containing something like `["string", "number"]` or possibly `["undefined", "undefined"]`, depending on the types of `x` and `y`.
2. `x = ["string", "number"][1]` takes the second element of that array and assigns it to `x`.
3. `typeof x` returns the type of `x` as the string `"string"`.
4. `typeof "string"` is `"string"`.

As to what the difference between `"undefined"` and `undefined` is: one is a string, the other an object. `typeof` always returns the type of the variable as a string, because you can redefine `undefined` to something else so you couldn't properly compare it anymore, but `"undefined" == "undefined"` is always true.