# typeof !== "undefined", comparing dates, new Date, Math.min / What is wrong with this simple js code?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, date, typeof

This code is on my nodeJS server. Every time the server gets to it, it crashes. Don't know what's wrong... Could someone help me?

`dateArray[11]`, `dateArray[12]` and `dateArray[13]` are either empty or are Date values.

```
var dateArray11 = null;
var tempDateValue = "";
if ((typeof dateArray[11] !== "undefined") || (typeof dateArray[12] !== "undefined") || (typeof dateArray[13] !== "undefined")) {
    dateArray11 = new Date(Math.min((dateArray[11].getTime()), (dateArray[12].getTime()), (dateArray[13].getTime())));
    if (dateArray11.getTime() === dateArray[11].getTime()) {
        tempDateValue = 11;
    }
    if (dateArray11.getTime() === dateArray[12].getTime()) {
        tempDateValue = 12;
    }
    if (dateArray11.getTime() === dateArray[13].getTime()) {
        tempDateValue = 13;
    }
}
```

Comment: You could make sure they're date objects by using `instanceof Date`.

Comment: That's what I was trying to do with (typeof Date !== "undefined"). Is it wrong? Didn't have any issues with it till now...

Comment: Shouldn't the condition be `&&` instead of `||`

Comment: not really, I want it to be "if at least one of them exists, take the lowest date of the ones that exist, then define the corresponding tempDateValue"

But maybe I can't use .getTime() with values that don't exist.  Maybe it is the issue!?

Comment: Thanks @KaranPunamiya I think we found the issue.

Comment: Saying the server "crashes" means something different from the server "issues a run-time error".

Comment: @torazaburo Thanks for letting me know! I will use the appropriate terminology next time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you said that dateArray[11], dateArray[12] and dateArray[13] are either empty or are Date values.

You cannot call a getTime() function of an empty or undefined value.

Before you call it, you should check if dateArray[11], dateArray[12] and dateArray[13] are Date Objects.
You can see how to check that in this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/643827/3442014

---

EDIT:
This is my aproach of what you're doing:

```js
var dateArray=[];
dateArray[11]=new Date("2011/06/31");
dateArray[12]=new Date("2011/06/26");
dateArray[13]="";

var tempDateValue = "";

var dates=[];
if (dateArray[11] instanceof Date) dates.push(dateArray[11]);
if (dateArray[12] instanceof Date) dates.push(dateArray[12]);
if (dateArray[13] instanceof Date) dates.push(dateArray[13]);

var min = new Date(Math.min.apply(null,dates));

var tempDateValue = dates.map(Number).indexOf(+min) + 11;
```

Comment: it'll not give object type of Date it just give you object even if you check typeof null, it will give you `object` :)

Comment: @Federicorp As I said, I want it to be : "if at least one of them exists, take the lowest date of the ones that exist, then define the corresponding tempDateValue" .

So you're right, this is the issue, but I don't want to check if dateArray[11], dateArray[12] AND dateArray[13] are Date Objects, because not all of them are. 

I will have to find another way to make it work.

Comment: Thanks for your elaborate answer!  In the meantime I figured it out.  The part I was missing was that I didn't need to .getTime() date values in an array before I could Math.min.apply(null, the array.

Answer (score 0):

> typeof(new Date()) is always give you an `object` and you are comparing it with `String` since typeof("undefined") is `String`.

```
console.log(typeof 123)// return number

console.log(typeof new Date())// return object

console.log(typeof 'hola')//return string
```

The typeof operator returns type information as a string. There are six possible values that typeof returns: "number," "string," "boolean," "object," "function," and "undefined."
The parentheses are optional in the typeof syntax.

Comment: typeof is an operator that always returns a string, describing the type of a value ...

see for example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5663356/6814172

Comment: Nope it'll not return always `String`

console.log(typeof(new Date())); it'll return `object`

Comment: Do you have some reference?   This page says it always returns a string: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof .

Comment: Can you print above console in your browser's console?

Comment: see the reference here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/259s7zc1(v=vs.94).aspx

Comment: search `typeof operator in javascript` Google give you exact answer

Comment: If still you have doubt then you can print above console and clear your doubt

Comment: My console won't be much help because it only says "POST /submitDetails 500 35.562 ms - 1314".

Comment: By the way, the link you gave me says typeof always returns a string.