# Why x equals to 1 in a result of `var y = 1, x = y = typeof x;`? (Chrome)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Can't understand why x is not equal to "undefined" evaluating following code in Google Chrome console (Version 65.0.3325.181 (Official Build) (64-bit)).

```js
var y = 1, x = y = typeof x;
x;
```

Should be no spaces after `;`
I found this piece of code in one JS quiz.

Comment: What browser do you use? x is undefined for me

Comment: [See if your quesiton is similar to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5663277/what-is-the-difference-between-undefined-and-undefined)

Comment: *"Why x equals to 1 in a result of `var y = 1, x = y = typeof x;`?"* It doesn't, both `x` and `y` contain the string `"undefined"`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder 
So sorry guys, provided wrong example. Hate this myself.

Added browser version and fixed an example. + Added some notes.

Comment: `x` is still `"undefined"` with the updated question: https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2At9.png, https://i.stack.imgur.com/1pVAo.png, https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLIx3.png, https://i.stack.imgur.com/UA1Yo.png

Answer (score 2):

> Why x equals to 1 in a result of `var y = 1, x = y = typeof x;`?

It isn't, it's `"undefined"` (the string). I suspect you meant to ask why `x` *doesn't* equal `1` after that code runs. (Edit: Hmmm, or not, given your *"Can't understand why x is not equal to "undefined" in expression"*...)

The reason is that the code is effectively this:

```
var y, x;
y = 1;
x = y = typeof x;
```

So it

1. Declares `y` and `x`, both of which get their default value, `undefined`.
2. Assigns 1 to `y`.
3. Assigns `typeof x` to `y`. Since `x` contains `undefined`, `typeof x` is `"undefined"` (the type of `undefined`).
4. Assigns the value that was just assigned to `y` (`"undefined"`) to `x`.

The reason `x` receives `"undefined"` rather than `1` in that last step is that compound assignments (`x = y = typeof x`) are processed right-to-left. That's why `y` gets a new value on Step 3 above, and only after that does that value get copied to `x` in Step 4.

Comment: Sorry for the wrong example. Try to have no spaces after first x;
and add `x;` next line.

Comment: @Rantiev: See [my comment here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49477927/why-x-equals-to-1-in-a-result-of-var-y-1-x-y-typeof-x-chrome#comment85996086_49477927). Spaces are rarely significant in JS, certainly not after `x` in the above.

Comment: I understand why there could be "undefined", but when `x;` goes on next line, there is a "string"

Comment: @Rantiev: Again, see the answer. The value of `x` is `"undefined"` (the string). If you're talking about the `undefined` after the `var` statement, that's because `var` doesn't have a return value, so the console shows `undefined` for it. But your title talks about `x` being `1`, which isn't in any way related to the code you've shown.