# Gatsby window not available during server side rendering build error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I am trying to build my Gatsby site to deploy to production, but I have run into an issue which I believe is related to one line of code within my application where I use `window` to redirect to an external url that is retrieve from a GET request made on a button click. I tried to read through the [documentation on this issue](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/debugging-html-builds/) and attempted to use their window check conditional, but my redirect either didn't work or I received an error related to `Can't resolve 'module'`. Is there an alternative route to either replacing the use of `window` all together or fixing why this runs during build and causing the error?

Error:

```
failed Building static HTML for pages - 2.611s

 ERROR #95312

"window" is not available during server side rendering.
```

Error for code checking for window:

```
  WebpackError: ReferenceError: window is not defined
```

Code:

```
authClick(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({ authorizing: true }, ()=> {
            axios.get(auth_url)
                .then((res) => {
                    this.setState({
                        authorizing: false
                    })

                    window.location.replace(res.data) // Window call

                    // Attempt to fix the issue based on documentation
                    // if (typeof window !== `undefined`){ 
                    //     const module = require("module")
                    //     window.location.replace(res.data) 
                    // }
                }).catch((err) => {
                    console.log(err)
                })
        });
    }

// Component
    <button className="inline-flex items-center" onClick={this.authClick} disabled={this.state.authorizing}>
    Auth
    </button>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
const isBrowser = () => typeof window !== "undefined"
isBrowser() && window.location.replace(res.data)
```

If you want to use window.location then you have to check first then use it `isBrowser() && window.location.replace(res.data)` instade of `window.location.replace(res.data)`

Comment: `navigate` only works for internal routing. As has been said, the redirection is external therefore must be treated using `window`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my mistake, In this case  only option would be to check for browser first then call ```window.location.replace(res.data)```.

Comment: SO won't let me edit, but shouldn't you remove the quotation marks around `undefined`? @FerranBuireu

Comment: Nope, it's not the same because of the type of coercion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5663277/what-is-the-difference-between-undefined-and-undefined#:~:text=As%20to%20what%20the%20difference,%22undefined%22%20is%20always%20true.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't need to require any module based on the `window` availability, don't do it. In your case, you only need to make a redirection, not to importing any module.

Just:

```
authClick(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({ authorizing: true }, ()=> {
            axios.get(auth_url)
                .then((res) => {
                    this.setState({
                        authorizing: false
                    })

                     if (typeof window !== `undefined`){ 
                           window.location = res.data 
                     }
                }).catch((err) => {
                    console.log(err)
                })
        });
    }
```

Note the change of making a redirection with `window.location` but you can also use your `window.location.replace` if you want.

Answer (score 2):

The link to the documentation is correct the window is not available during the build process so you must define a check.

The term module in the documentation would be replaced by the actual name of the module you are referencing. Then you would wrap the import/require with the window check as mentioned in the documentation.

For your purposes the code would look like this:

```
...

if (typeof window !== `undefined`){
  window.location.replace(res.data) // Window call
}

...
```

You would not need the require module since you are not importing a module.

Hope that clarifies.

Answer (score 1):

Tip: put `typeof window !== 'undefined' && window.whaterver-you-need` to solve this.