# "window" is not available during server side rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

Trying to use [Isotope](https://isotope.metafizzy.co/) on Gatsby. Installed via `npm install isotope-layout`, then getting this error when  `gatsby-build` :

```
failed Building static HTML for pages - 2.369s

 ERROR #95312 

"window" is not available during server side rendering.

See our docs page for more info on this error: https://gatsby.dev/debug-html


  57 |   }
  58 |
> 59 | }( window, function factory( window, Outlayer, getSize, matchesSelector,
utils,
     |  ^
  60 |   Item, LayoutMode ) {
  61 |
  62 | 'use strict';


  WebpackError: ReferenceError: window is not defined
  
  - isotope.js:59 
    [gatsby-starter-blog]/[isotope-layout]/js/isotope.js:59:2

  - [...]
```

Tried to use a `useEffect()` as mentionned in [Gatsby doc](https://gatsby.dev/debug-html) :

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { graphql } from "gatsby"
import Layout from '../components/layout'
import Seo from "../components/seo"
import Isotope from 'isotope-layout/js/isotope';
import { useEffect } from 'react';

const Explore = ({ data, location }) => {

  const siteTitle = data.site.siteMetadata?.title || `Title`
  const allConcepts = data.allStrapiConcept?.edges

  const GridConstruction = () => {

    useEffect(() => {

      // Isotope initialisation
      let iso = new Isotope('.grid', {
        itemSelector: '.element-item',
        layoutMode: 'fitRows'
      })

      // Filtering functions
      let filters = {
        showConcepts: function (itemElem) {
          let type = itemElem.querySelector('.type').textContent
          return type.match(/Concept/)
        },
      }

      // Button click binding
      let filtersBlock = document.querySelector('.filters');

      filtersBlock.addEventListener('click', (e) => {

        // Bind to filtering function
        let filterValue = e.target.getAttribute('data-filter')
        filterValue = filters[filterValue] || filterValue

        // Filtering
        iso.arrange({ filter: filterValue })
      })

    })

    return (
      <div className='grid' style={{ border: '1px solid #333', minHeight: '531.251px' }}>
        {
          allConcepts ? 
            allConcepts.map(concept => (
              <a href={concept.node.slug} key={concept.node.id}>
                <span style={{ display: 'block', padding: '15px' }} className='element-item' key={concept.node.id}>
                  <h3 className='name'>{concept.node.titre}</h3>
                  <p className='type'>Concept</p>
                </span>
              </a>
            )) : ''
        }
      </div>
    )
  }

  return (
    <Layout location={location} title={siteTitle}>
      <Seo title='Explore' />
      <div className='button-group filters'>
        <button className='button' data-filter='*'>Tout montrer</button>
        <button className='button' data-filter='showConcepts'>Concepts</button>
      </div>
      <GridConstruction />
    </Layout>
  )
}

export default Explore

export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query {
    site {
      siteMetadata {
        title
      }
    allStrapiConcept {
      edges {
        node {
          id
          slug
          titre
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

Landing on the same error. Also tried the second solution mentioned in the same doc and in [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64371186/gatsby-window-not-available-during-server-side-rendering-build-error):

```
const isBrowser = typeof window !== "undefined"

const Explore = ({ data, location }) => {

  // Getting values from from GraphQL PageQuery
  const siteTitle = data.site.siteMetadata?.title || `Title`
  const allConcepts = data.allStrapiConcept?.edges

  // Grid construction
  const GridConstruction = () => {

    if (isBrowser) {

      // Isotope initialisation
      let iso = new Isotope('.grid', {
        itemSelector: '.element-item',
        layoutMode: 'fitRows'
      })

      // Filtering functions
      let filters = {
        showConcepts: function (itemElem) {
          let type = itemElem.querySelector('.type').textContent
          return type.match(/Concept/)
        },
      }

      // Button click binding
      let filtersBlock = document.querySelector('.filters');

      filtersBlock.addEventListener('click', (e) => {

        // Bind to filtering function
        let filterValue = e.target.getAttribute('data-filter')
        filterValue = filters[filterValue] || filterValue

        // Filtering
        iso.arrange({ filter: filterValue })
      })

    }

    return (
      <div className='grid' style={{ border: '1px solid #333', minHeight: '531.251px' }}>
        {
          allConcepts ? 
            allConcepts.map(concept => (
              <a href={concept.node.slug} key={concept.node.id}>
                <span style={{ display: 'block', padding: '15px' }} className='element-item' key={concept.node.id}>
                  <h3 className='name'>{concept.node.titre}</h3>
                  <p className='type'>Concept</p>
                </span>
              </a>
            )) : ''
        }
      </div>
    )
  }
```

Which lands on the same error.

I understand that `window` because there is no browser during build time, but it felt like at least `useEffect()` should work. Also, code works fine with `gatsby develop?`.

Feels like I'm missing something. Any hint ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Gatsby window not available during server side rendering build error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64371186/gatsby-window-not-available-during-server-side-rendering-build-error)

Comment: No, I think I already tried that option in the last portion of code above. I can't figure out why neither useEffect() or isBrowser check is working.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `isBrowser` inside the `useEffect` dependency array.

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import Head from "next/head";

const App = () => {
  const isBrowser = typeof window !== "undefined";

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isBrowser) {
      // Your code here
    }
  }, [isBrowser]);

  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <title>Trying out next.js</title>
      </Head>
      <h2 className="boxed">Testing Example</h2>
    </div>
  );
};

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```